# Is there any way to know whether a cloudberry backup is running a full or block level backup?

Tags: cloudberry

Is there any way to know whether a cloudberry backup is running a full or block level backup? I have searched through the interface and I can't find anything to say which it's actually running at any one time other than extrapolating the information from the edit screen.

**EDIT:**

Screenshot of the "schedule full backup" page from the Local to Cloud wizard.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Our software runs forever incremental - that means, that after the first full backup we upload only the changed parts of files. 
However, we do not do the forever block level backup. Block level is available only in advanced mode. You should choose advanced mode and after that, from advanced settings, you should enable block level.
To learn more about our features, please check out the blog: http://cloudberrylab.com/blog

Comment: Sorry if my question is confusing I think it might be - I shouldn't have said anything about block level backups at all I think. Really the question I should have asked instead is: "For plans that have a full backup schedule: — While the backup is running is there any way to see whether it's a full backup that's running — or not" - By "scheduled" I'm specifically referring to how you can schedule a full backup on the "Full Backup Options" page of the "Edit Backup Plan" Wizard

Comment: If you are running file level backup - there is no way to schedule a so-called "true full backup" - that means that we won't re-backup ALL files once again, we simply will check all files on the storage and backup only changed and new ones.

Comment: If the backup type in question is image based - then in real-time you can only tell if the backup is full from the logs of the plan. After the backup was taken, you can go to backup storage tab and see if backup is full or differential.

Comment: Ok I'm confused. In cloudberry backup on the HOME tab I click Local to Cloud and I'm presented with a wizard. On the 5th page of the wizard ( advanced options ) ... if I tick "use block level backup" then a new page appears in the wizard after the 10th page schedule - this new page is titled "full backup options" ,,,, and I get an option to schedule a new backup - I will attach a screenshot to my question

Comment: Unfortunately, cannot see a screenshot. However, regarding the block level backup - you schedule full backup there. I think, there might be a misunderstanding - check out that article: https://www.cloudberrylab.com/blog/cloudberry-backup-block-level-backup-scheduling-full-backup/

Comment: not sure why you cant see the screenshot, it's in my question ( above - since I can't add it in a comment ) ... but anyway it's essentially the same as the screenshot in the link you gave - my question is whether there is any way to tell that a backup is running a scheduled full backup or not